# Using an Archimesh glass panes pixelates my HDRI background – anyone know why?

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting, glass, hdri

I'm new to Blender and the tutorial I'm following uses Archimesh to create basic glass doors. Using both the default Archimesh shading settings and my own custom settings (see screenshot below), the panes pixelate the HDRI background (I've hidden one of the panes so that the difference is clear).

I haven't found anyone online with this same issue – would anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance! I've had a million dumb questions but this is the only one I haven't been able to find a solution for.

[image: Screenshot of blender window]

Comment: Maybe a set the IOR to 1.0

Answer (score 2):

Turn off half res trace under SSR in Eevee:

[image]

Comment: Just did and it didn't seem to do anything. I'm on a new Macbook with an M1 chip – think that could have anything to do w/ it? Edit: https://imgur.com/a/GbO5hcw

Comment: Then you are magnifying an already low res HDRI with the default IOR. Try lowering ior or using a better hdri.